# customization of dropwizard initial unauthorized message to json format in Java

Tags: java, json, jersey, dropwizard

We are using the dropwizard 0.9.X, we have customized class written to authenticate the token entered by the users before retrieving the data. I want customize the initial unauthorized message "Credentials are required to access this resource." to JSON format and i would like to display like below.

```js
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "HTTP 401 Unauthorized, Credentials are required to access this resource."
}
```

I have written AbstractStatusType to implement the StatusType and I am able to print the above format message whenever users enter invalid token or expired token. Example bearer 03cb9ebe-1c66-4d08-b9a4-afe69989ef21

But I am still getting plain text response body as "Credentials are required to access this resource." when users enter only "bearer" or only token "03cb9ebe-1c66-4d08-b9a4-afe69989ef21".

Could you please help me to customize the above text format message to above JSON format?

Below is the customized code which is setting response "Credentials are required to access this resource." which internally using dropwizard OAuthCredentialAuthFilter class

```
public AuthDynamicFeature getAuthFilter(CachingAuthenticator<String, AuthenticatedPrincipal> cachingAuthenticator) {
    OAuthCredentialAuthFilter<AuthenticatedPrincipal> authFilter = new OAuthCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<AuthenticatedPrincipal>()
            .setAuthenticator(cachingAuthenticator)
            .setAuthorizer(new OAuthAuthorizer())
            .setRealm(REALM)
            .setPrefix(PREFIX)
            .buildAuthFilter();
    return new AuthDynamicFeature(authFilter);
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

@Arthur,

I have implemented UnauthorizedHandler with JsonUnauthorizedHandler as below and it worked fine me.

```
public class JsonUnauthorizedHandler implements UnauthorizedHandler {
    private static final String CHALLENGE_FORMAT = "%s realm=\"%s\"";

    @Override
    public Response buildResponse(String prefix, String realm) {
        // Create an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response with a JSON payload of a
        // human readable error
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE,
                        String.format(CHALLENGE_FORMAT, prefix, realm))
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .entity(ImmutableMap.of("code","401",
                        "message",
                        "HTTP 401 Unauthorized, Credentials are required to access this resource."))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Then i have set this as below getAuthFilter.

```
public AuthDynamicFeature getAuthFilter(CachingAuthenticator<String, AuthenticatedPrincipal> cachingAuthenticator) {
    OAuthCredentialAuthFilter<AuthenticatedPrincipal> authFilter = new OAuthCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<AuthenticatedPrincipal>()
            .setAuthenticator(cachingAuthenticator)
            .setAuthorizer(new OAuthAuthorizer())
            .setRealm(REALM)
            .setPrefix(PREFIX)
            .setUnauthorizedHandler(new JsonUnauthorizedHandler())
            .buildAuthFilter();
    return new AuthDynamicFeature(authFilter);
}
```

Below is the response i have received on swagger post the above changes.

```
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "HTTP 401 Unauthorized, Credentials are required to access this resource."
}
```

Thanks for your suggestion on this.

Thanks
Rags

Comment: Glad you found it :) Tagging me @Artur won't give me a notification which is why I did not see your follow up. You need to use my username for that :)

Answer (score 1):

For this, you need to set the UnauthorizedHandler on DW:

```
public AuthDynamicFeature getAuthFilter(CachingAuthenticator<String, AuthenticatedPrincipal> cachingAuthenticator) {
    OAuthCredentialAuthFilter<AuthenticatedPrincipal> authFilter = new OAuthCredentialAuthFilter.Builder<AuthenticatedPrincipal>()
            .setAuthenticator(cachingAuthenticator)
            .setAuthorizer(new OAuthAuthorizer())
            .setRealm(REALM)
            .setPrefix(PREFIX)
            .setUnauthorizedHandler(new MyUnauthorizedHandler())
            .buildAuthFilter();
    return new AuthDynamicFeature(authFilter);
}
```

The `setUnauthorizedHandler` method sets this property.

You can then customise the response by implementing that interface:

```
public static class MyUnauthorizedHandler implements UnauthorizedHandler {

        @Override
        public Response buildResponse(String prefix, String realm) {
            return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("").build();
        }

    }
```

Hope that helps,

Artur

Comment: @Artur, Thanks for your suggestion, with above solution i will be able to print the message which I want but i am not getting the JSON format message.  I am just getting plan text format.   Can you suggest me how can i print the JSON format message?  Thanks.  is there any way to set the JSON format message instead of plan text format?  Thanks for your help in advance!